# Writing multiple CSV files from Api result

Tags: python, csv

Hello please I am trying to write multiple CSV files  TSRP_list to contain each specific binary values which I print out using an API and I would like to print the CSV with the list Tag name

obj_TriangulatedSetRepresentation_038ed42e-967e-4143-adfa-b94c00adb02e.xml
obj_TriangulatedSetRepresentation_07359470-d721-474b-81cd-7886bd4e2f8e.xml

what i did

```
with open('obj_TriangulatedSetRepresentation_126af84e-0a9b-407d-8036- 
     1ffc316106dd.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
            thewriter = csv.writer(f)
            thewriter.writerow(['X', 'Y' ,'Z'])
            thewriter.writerows(value_json["value"])
```

what i am trying to do

```
for TSRP in TSRP_list[0:3]:
    TSRP = TSRP.strip('/')
    print TSRP
    csv_filename = 'TSRP' + '.csv'
    with open(csv_filename, 'w', newline='') as f:
        thewriter = csv.writer(f)
        thewriter.writerow(['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
        thewriter.writerows(value_json['value'])
```

I do not get an error but rather a single csv

Comment: You're always using the same csv file name, so basically at each iteration you'll overwrite what you've written at the previous iteration. You need separate file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the filename to `TSRP.csv` in each iteration of the loop, in the line:

```
csv_filename = 'TSRP' + '.csv'
```

So you will overwrite the previous file with each iteration.

You probably meant something like:

```
csv_filename = TSRP + '.csv'
```

to use the variable `TSRP` instead of the string `'TSRP'`

Comment: @musaabdullahi I'm glad. Can you please accept the answer? Thanks

Comment: sorry this my first question on this platform idk if there method of answering

Comment: Thanks, and welcome to the community ;) Here is a quick [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of StackOverflow